# How do I re-open a file in emacs?

Tags: emacs

In older emacs versions I used to type:

```
C-x C-f RET
```

And it would re-open the file currently visited in the buffer.  Now (emacs 23.1.1) it opens Dired of the directory.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use `M-x find-alternate-file` which is by default bound to `C-x C-v`.

This command allows to reload a file onto the current buffer, reloading the same file include - which is shown in the mini-buffer by default.
This is however not as convenient  if you have ido-mode enabled for buffer-switching as it will not display the current file name by default.

Comment: Other answers were excellent, too, but this answer has the fewest keystrokes.

Comment: This method triggers the mode hook, while Gilles' answer, `find-file`, won't trigger it.

Answer (score 11):

Are you sure you don't want to just revert the buffer?

```
M-x revert-buffer RET
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do `C-x C-f M-n RET`. The behavior was changed because `C-x C-f RET` to reopen a file wasn't nearly as common as `C-x C-f DEL RET` to invoke Dired on the directory.

You can also use `M-x revert-buffer` to reload a file from disk, and Emacs will tell you (on most operating systems) if you try to edit a file whose copy on disk has been modified externally.

`C-x C-f M-n` is also useful to obtain the full path to the file in the minibuffer, so you can open a file with a similar name or copy it to the kill ring or clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

I found a useful suggestion to go back to the previous behaviour of `C-x C-f RET` on [help-gnu-emacs mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-02/msg00241.html):

This hack was posted by Ted Stern:

```
(defun find-file-read-args (prompt mustmatch)
  (list (let ((find-file-default
           (and buffer-file-name
                (abbreviate-file-name buffer-file-name))))
      (read-file-name prompt nil find-file-default mustmatch))
    t))
```

I tried it out and it works well for me on emacs 23.1.1.